# STTwitterAPI to pull number of tweets,followers and following?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I am trying to create a profile inside my application to show only his twitter profile. So far I do have the time line working but I don't have the number counter for the tweets,followers and following. I'm pretty sure I can use something what my code looks like but just don't know how, any help? Thanks

Code:

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:@"ConsumerKey"
                                                        consumerSecret:@"consumerSecret"];

[twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *bearerToken) {

    [twitter getUserTimelineWithScreenName:@"MikesiOSHelp"
                              successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {

                                  self.twitterFeed = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:statuses];

                                  [self->tableView reloadData];

                              } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

                                  NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);

                              }];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);

}];
```

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Nothing, the code I posted is to get the TimeLine, not the tweets,followers and following.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out their [demo application](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter#demo--test-project).

Your request for finding the followers of a user is [explicitly covered](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/demo_cli/followers/main.m) in the CLI demo:

```
typedef void (^AllFollowersBlock_t)(NSArray *allFollowers);

void getFollowers(STTwitterAPI *twitter,
                  NSString *screenName,
                  NSMutableArray *followers,
                  NSString *cursor,
                  AllFollowersBlock_t allFollowersBlock) {

    if(followers == nil) followers = [NSMutableArray array]; 

    NSMutableDictionary *md = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    md[@"screen_name"] = screenName;
    if(cursor) md[@"cursor"] = cursor;
    md[@"skip_status"] = @"1";
    md[@"include_user_entities"] = @"0";

    [twitter getResource:@"followers/list.json"
           baseURLString:kBaseURLStringAPI_1_1
              parameters:md
   downloadProgressBlock:^(id json) {
       //
   } successBlock:^(NSDictionary *rateLimits, id response) {

       NSArray *users = nil;
       NSString *previousCursor = nil;
       NSString *nextCursor = nil;

       if([response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
           users = [response valueForKey:@"users"];
           previousCursor = [response valueForKey:@"previous_cursor_str"];
           nextCursor = [response valueForKey:@"next_cursor_str"];
       }

       NSLog(@"-- users: %@", @([users count]));
       NSLog(@"-- previousCursor: %@", previousCursor);
       NSLog(@"-- nextCursor: %@", nextCursor);

       [followers addObjectsFromArray:users];

       if([nextCursor integerValue] == 0) {
           allFollowersBlock(followers);
           return;
       }

       /**/

       NSString *remainingString = [rateLimits objectForKey:@"x-rate-limit-remaining"];
       NSString *resetString = [rateLimits objectForKey:@"x-rate-limit-reset"];

       NSInteger remainingInteger = [remainingString integerValue];
       NSInteger resetInteger = [resetString integerValue];
       NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 0;

       if(remainingInteger == 0) {

           NSDate *resetDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:resetInteger];
           timeInterval = [resetDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]] + 5;

       }

       NSLog(@"-- wait for %@ seconds", @(timeInterval));

       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(timeInterval * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           getFollowers(twitter, screenName, followers, nextCursor, allFollowersBlock);

       });

   } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"-- error: %@", error);
   }];
}
```